Stopping the execute of a script
I am working with an express application and I want a script to execute passed on the URL only once
I tried this
app.get("/api/user/med", (req, res) => {
  try {
      console.log(req.query.name)
      const { name } = req.query;
      const { expy } = req.query;
      const { quan } = req.query;
      const { place } = req.query;
      console.log(name)
      var sql =
        "INSERT INTO medicine (med_name, expiry, quantity, place) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)";
      var values = [name, expy, quan, place];
      if (name != null && name != undefined){
      console.log(req.query)
      req.query = ""
      req.url = req.query
      console.log(req.url)
      const putMed = client.query(sql, values, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM medicine";
  client.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.render("index.ejs", { resultRows: result. Rows });
  });
      });
      putMed;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});

But when I refresh the page, it inserts again so how could I stop that?
Thanks in Advance.

Do you mean you only want the db insert to happen once? You'll need to check if it exists and do nothing if it does. Also, why do you have just putMed; hanging out down there?

The question doesn't make sense without context. It's unknown under which condition this endpoint is requested. If this occurs on certain page route, then a redirect needs to be performed on success.

Well, a refresh naturally requests the same URL over again which will call your route again.  That is what it is supposed to do.  For starters, you are modifying your database based on a GET request.  That's not what you are supposed to do.  You should be using either a POST or a PUT depending upon the details of the database operation.

Also, if (err) throw err; in an asynchronous callback is horrible error handling.  Send a real error status back to the client when you get an error.

Thanks for your help @jfriend00. Could you add this as an answer?

Per your request, I added an answer below.

A refresh naturally requests the same URL over again which will call your route again. That is what it is supposed to do.
For starters, you are modifying your database based on a GET request. That's not what you are supposed to do. You should be using either a POST or a PUT or a PATCH depending upon the details of the kind of change you are making.  If you're not familiar with the standard uses of GET, PUT, POST, etc... there are many, many sites you can read about using these properly.  The general topic is called REST (representational state transfer) and here's one article about it.  You can search for many more references on the topic.
The general idea is that each REST URL represents a particular resource on the server or a particular operation and you're doing one of these operations on that resource.
Here's a summary:

GET: Retrieves a resource or collection of resources.
POST: Creates a new resource or submits data for processing.
PUT: Updates an existing resource fully by replacing it with new data.
PATCH: Partially updates a resource with specific changes.
DELETE: Removes a resource.

Note that a GET request does not modify a resource on the server.  It will fetch a resource and will often be cacheable.

You should also fix your error handling here to send an error response back to the client.  Doing throw err inside an asynchronous callback will not do anything useful as there's none of your code that can handle that thrown exception.
So, change this:
  const putMed = client.query(sql, values, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    getAllMed(res);
  });

to something like this:
  const putMed = client.query(sql, values, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // send some sort of meaningful error response here
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
    }
    getAllMed(res);
  });

